# Function For Sine Wave Between Two Exponential Cuves

Tags: functions

What function could I use to approximate a curve with this plot?

[image]

The function ideally will involve sine and have its envelope defined by different exponentials of the form $y = ae^{bx}$ and $y = ce^{dx}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $f$ and $g$ are any two functions with $f<g$ you can get a sinewave-ish thing oscillating between $f$ and $g$ by considering $$\frac{f(x)+g(x)}2+\frac{f(x)-g(x)}2\sin(x).$$

Or $$\frac{f(x)+g(x)}2+\frac{f(x)-g(x)}2\phi(x),$$if $\phi$ is any function that oscillates between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: Just so the answer is clear to anyone else, here $f(x) = ce^{dx}$ and $g(x) = ae^{bx}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$c\exp\left(dx+(bx-dx+\ln a-\ln c)\sin^2 x\right)$$
Edit
$$ce^{dx}+(ae^{bx}-ce^{dx})\sin^2(kx)$$

Comment: It looks as good an option as any. In theory we could replace $\sin^2 x$ with, say, $\sin^{2k}(x+\phi)$.

Comment: Yes or $\sin^{2k}(kx+\phi)$

Comment: Or $\sin^{2k}(cx+\phi)$.

Comment: Do you care to share what is the intuition behind the first expression?

Comment: Take logs, get straight lines; put the sinewave between them; and exponentiate to put them back